# Read txt file from drawable folder in android

Tags: android, android-file

How to read .txt file from drawable or any other folder in android using FileInputStream?

I have a .txt file in my drawable folder. How can i read the file and set it in Textview?

Comment: Do you know `"Google"`? It's the better browser to search problems, for example `"How to read files Android"`, try it, Google it's your friend.

Comment: You can't place your .txt under drawable, the compile tools will complain error. It must be .xml or .png file.

Comment: put your text file into assets folder

Comment: `Read txt file from drawable folder` it's **not possible**.

Comment: Sadly, there is comparatively very low patience in Android Dev community.

Answer (score 3):

**Try This with help of this u can read file from drawable folder**

```
        String data = "";
        StringBuffer sbuffer = new StringBuffer();
        InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(+
                R.drawable.filetoread);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        if (is != null) {
            try {
                while ((data = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sbuffer.append(data + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
         data = sbuffer.toString(),
        }
```

Comment: Despite text files shouldn't be in the drawable folder as stated by @Abdul Fatir, this is useful to copy, for example, gif files that cannot be copied as a bitmap.